# android sdk facebook circle activity

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, sdk, geometry

So basically I am trying to draw a circle activity or a button that stays on top of all views, just like facebooks circles.

I've been searching like crazy but I have not found anything related. Anything would help that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I am not able to understand.. CAn you give more descreption

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but what I am searching for is somehow creating a small button or activity that stays on top of all the other activities.Facebook has this feature, the chat circles with peoples profile picture.

Comment: In which app. Can u post a snapshot?

Comment: I found this when googling http://www.wnwdesign.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Facebook-App-update-04-2013-001.jpg.

I know it is iOS but it should be possible to do it with Android aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know the exact answer, but here is a library that hovers over any application .

Here is a demo [video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3vHjxonOeg)

Check this out. [StandOutLibrary.](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut)

You may find it usefull.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but I'll accept it anyway, cool project.